# Hiding a row from a page that is passed as html file into a stringbuilder type object

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an html page for a preview functionality.
I pass this as html into a stringbuilder type object and replace content through another page.
Now I want a certain section to be hidden under a specific circumstnace.
Currently that section is a row.
So how can I do so?

The following code in the section I want to hide:

```
<tr id="rowcontent" bgcolor="E96F00">
<td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; font-weight: Bold; color:white;">Course Content Link</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 14px;">@CourseContent@<BR>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

This is how I am using the above html :

```
file = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Template\\Level100_Template.htm";
string input = string.Empty;
if (File.Exists(file))
{
sr = File.OpenText(file);
//input += Server.HtmlEncode(sr.ReadToEnd());
input += sr.ReadToEnd();
x.Append(input);
sr.Close();
}
```

This is how I am replacing the content section:

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["CourseContentPath"].ToString() != string.Empty)
    {x.Replace   ("@CourseContent@", "<A href='" +CourseContentLink   + "' target=_blank onclick='window.open(this.href,           this.target,'height=1000px,width=1000px'); return false>Click here</A> to find the course content");
    }
```

How can I hide the entire section in a particular case..

Comment: Do u wanna find that rows in x and remove them?

Comment: Yes..or any other way..I need to hide that section-that is the motive.

Answer (score 0):

A simplest way is to use this code

```
string StartStr= "<tr id=\"rowcontent\"", EndStr= "</tr>", String= x.ToString();
int Start= String.IndexOf(StartStr);
int End= String.IndexOf(EndStr, String.IndexOf(EndStr, Start)+ EndStr.Length);
x.Remove(Start,End- Start+ EndStr.Length);
```